# How to resolve promises one after another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

How could I fire off promises one after the other?

`waitFor(t)`, is a function that returns a promise that resolves after `t` time. What I wish to be able to do with that is:

```
waitFor(1000) Then when finished, console.log('Finished wait of 1000 millis') then
waitFor(2000) Then when finished, console.log('Finished wait of 2000 millis') then
waitFor(3000) Then when finished, console.log('Finished wait of 3000 millis')
```

Here is what I tried:

```
waitFor(1000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(resolve);
}).then(waitFor(2000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(resolve);
})).then(waitFor(3000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(resolve);
}));
```

Unfortunately this console.logs the statements each 1 second after another, which means that the promises where all called at once.

I managed to fix this with callbacks like so, yet that makes everything very ugly:

```
waitFor(1000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(resolve+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds()));
    waitFor(2000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(resolve+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds()));
        waitFor(3000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log(resolve+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds()));
        });
    });
});
```

So how should I do this with promises that makes it work, yet isn't using ugly callback hell?

Undesired result: http://jsfiddle.net/nxjd563r/1/

Desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/4xxps2cg/

Comment: This might help - http://tech.transferwise.com/making-serial-xhr-calls-in-angularjs/

Comment: I'm not even using angularjs....

Comment: I pointed to the blog to get an idea - go for a recursive function which will go through your array of promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your solution.

You need to have each `then` to return a new promise, so that the next `then` can react once the previous one has been resolved.

```
waitFor(1000).then(function(result) {
    $('#result').append(result+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds())+'<br>');
    return waitFor(2000);
}).then(function(result) {
    $('#result').append(result+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds())+'<br>');
    return waitFor(3000);
}).then(function(result) {
    $('#result').append(result+' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds())+'<br>');
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4xxps2cg/2/

Comment: Glad to have helped, Max!

Comment: Please fix the arguments `resolve, reject`.   What is passed to a `.then()` handler is one single value which shouldn't be named `resolve` or `reject`.

Comment: Fixed as per @jfriend00 suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can put promises into array and use `reduce` to chain them, starting with one extra resolved promise.

```
function waitPromise(time) {
  //console.log(time);
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {resolve('resolved');}, time);
  });
}

function log(data) {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    console.log( data +' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds()));
    resolve();
  });
}

var ps = [];
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  let time = (i+1) * 1000;
  ps.push( () => waitPromise(time) );
  ps.push( log );
}


console.log( 'started' +' @ '+(new Date().getSeconds()));
var p = Promise.resolve();
ps.reduce( (p,c) => {return p.then(c)}, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

`waitFor()` appear to be called immediately at `.then()` ; try returning `waitFor()` from within `.then()` anonymous function.

Could alternatively create array of duration values , use `Array.prototype.shift()` to call `waitFor` with each duration value in succession , or pass parameter `timeout` to `waitFor` ; if same process called at each `.then()` , include process at `.then()` chained to `Promise` in `waitFor` ; call same function `waitFor` at `.then()` chained to initial `waitFor()` call

```
var t = [1000, 2000, 3000];
function waitFor(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("`Finished waiting ${timeout} milliseconds`");
        }, timeout && t.shift() || t.shift());
    }).then(function (data) {
      $('#result').append(data + ' @ ' + new Date().getSeconds() + '<br/>'); 
    })
}

waitFor().then(waitFor).then(waitFor)
//.then(function() {return waitFor(5000)})
```

Comment: Why is there only one return?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz  initial `waitFor` returns initial `Promise` , `.then()` following initial call to `waitFor(1000)` only needed to return promise to last `.then()` in chain

Answer (score 1):

The format for calling and waiting is a bit off, your `then` should be a function that returns a promise, since now you're passing a function call instead of a function, its running that request instantly instead of waiting to call the function as a result of the promise.

This should do it:

```
function waitFor(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(`Finished waiting ${timeout} milliseconds`);
        }, timeout);
    });
}

waitFor(1000).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    $('#result').append(resolve+' @ '+new Date().getSeconds()+'<br/>');
}).then(function(){
    return waitFor(2000)
}).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    $('#result').append(resolve+' @ '+new Date().getSeconds()+'<br/>');
}).then(function() {
    return waitFor(2000)
}).then(function(resolve, reject) {
    $('#result').append(resolve+' @ '+new Date().getSeconds()+'<br/>');
})
```