# Javascript Promise with Await Explanation

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I would just like to *understand* how promises and await work together. Look at the following code:

```
console.log("One: Started");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("One: Completed")}, 1000);
console.log("Two: Started");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Two: Completed")}, 2000);
console.log("Three: Started");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Three: Completed")}, 3000);
```

So this of course logs:

```
One: Started
Two: Started
Three: Started
One: Completed
Two: Completed
Three: Completed
```

I would like to have the one complete before the next one starts. I wrote this with my understanding of promises and await but this is not working. Would someone please try and edit this code to get it working. **And please and an explanation as I am trying to understand promises and await**

```
async function LogAll() {
    console.log("One: Started");
    await function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("One: Completed");
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    console.log("Two: Started");
    await function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("Two: Completed");
                resolve();
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    console.log("Three: Started");
    await function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("Three: Completed");
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}

LogAll();
```

Comment: Just add `();` at the end of your function definitions coming right after `await` to make them invoked and return promises. You don't need to bracket the whole function. You may also have a look into [how you may sequence promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098346/4543207)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to `await` *promises*, not functions alone. When you `await function ...` (without calling it), the function is evaluated as an expression and then discarded. Just call the functions:

```js
async function LogAll() {
  console.log("One: Started");
  await (function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("One: Completed");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  })();
  console.log("Two: Started");
  await (function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Two: Completed");
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    });
  })();
  console.log("Three: Started");
  await (function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Three: Completed");
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  })();
}

LogAll();
```

Or, for this example, don't use functions at all - just await the promises directly:

```js
async function LogAll() {
  console.log("One: Started");
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("One: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  console.log("Two: Started");
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Two: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
  console.log("Three: Started");
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Three: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

LogAll();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect. Sorry for the noob question XD But this teaches me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `async function` declaration defines an `asynchronous function`, which returns an AsyncFunction object.

An `async function` can contain an `await` expression that pauses the execution of the `async function` and waits for the passed `Promise's` resolution, and then resumes the `async function's` execution and returns the resolved value.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('calling');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
  console.log('called');
}

asyncCall();
```

For More refer [Async Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

**What is an async Function:**

It is a function which returns a AsyncFunction Object, similar to Promises. If it throws an error, the object rejects, otherwise when it returns a value, it resolves.

Async Functions are newer and before they existed there were different ways to write asynchronous code: Promises (part of rxjs), Observables ("infinite Promises"), callbacks used with timing events.

**What is the await keyword:**

In Javascript the `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` Function with the following syntax:

`[returnValue] = await expression;`

Where the expression can be a Promise or any other value returned by asynchronous code.

`await` tells the code to stop and wait for that value.

Without that, the `returnValue` in the above expression would be immediately given a value (undefined most probably) and the code will continue without blocking. After some unknown time and unknown point in the code, the function will finally return and `returnValue` will finally receive the correct value. But maybe the code went forward and wrongly assumed you already had a defined and updated value, possibly failing.

Try to run the snippets without async await. They are counter examples to show the corresponding synchronous code:

**EXAMPLE 1: all Promises are started immediately**

```js
function LogAll() {
  console.log("One: Started");
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("One: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  console.log("Two: Started");
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Two: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
  console.log("Three: Started");
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Three: Completed");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

LogAll();
```

**EXAMPLE 2: No promises at all (identical results to example 1)**

```js
function LogAll() {
      console.log("One: Started");

        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("One: Completed");
        }, 1000);

      console.log("Two: Started");

        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("Two: Completed");
        }, 2000);

      console.log("Three: Started");

        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("Three: Completed");
        }, 3000);
        
    }

    LogAll();
```

In Example 2 please note that setTimeout is a timing event, an older feature of Javascript, so it does not really need a wrapper Promise, except the Promise allows you to throw errors and reject.