# React how to call 1 promise after the previous promise is finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React hook with this structure. What I want to do is, after finish calling `getUserJoinedSlotList()` and getting the result, then I want to call `getAllAvailableSlot()` both set the result into the `useState` hooks.

```
const [joinedSlotList, setJoinedSlotList] = useState(null)
const [availableSlotList, setAvailableSlotList] = useState(null)
const [isAllSlotLoading, setIsAllSlotLoading] = useState(true)

const getJoinedList = () => {
        getUserJoinedSlotList()
            .then(res => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setJoinedSlotList(res.joined_slot)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setErrorMsg(error.message)

            })
    }


const getAvailableSlotList = () => {
        getAllAvailableSlot()
            .then(res => {
                setIsAllSlotLoading(false)  // this setting not working, at the 2nd API call
                setAllAvailableSlotList(res.slot)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setAvailableErrMsg(error.message)
                setIsAllSlotLoading(false)
            })
    }

useEffect(() => {
        if (user !== null) {
            getJoinedList()
         }
    }, [user])
```

Here is the code for getAvailableSlot(), I am using Aws amplify, so it actually return a promise for the `GET` request

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

export const getAllAvailableSlot = async () => {
    let path2 = path + '/list_all'

    return API.get(apiName, path2)
}
```

**What I tried:**

Put in `getAvailableSlotList` as a callback function of `getJoinedList()`, like this:

```
const getJoinedList = (callback) => {
        getUserJoinedSlotList()
            .then(res => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setJoinedSlotList(res.joined_slot)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setErrorMsg(error.message)

            })

        callback()
    }

then
useEffect(() => {
        if (user !== null) {
            getJoinedList(getAvailableSlotList) // put in as call back here
         }
    }, [user])
```

By this, `getAllAvailableSlot` is called, I getting the result. But the result is not being set after calling `setAvailableSlotList`, and `setIsAllSlotLoading(false)` is not working as well, still `true`

Then I tried to call like this:

```
const getJoinedList = () => {
        getUserJoinedSlotList()
            .then(res => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setJoinedSlotList(res.joined_slot)

               

                getAvailableSlotList() // here call the function 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                setErrorMsg(error.message)

            })
    }
```

Again, is same result as above attempt.

Then I tried like this as well:

```
const calling = async () => {
        await getJoinedList()
        await getAvailableSlotList() //setAvailableSlotList and setAllIsLoading is not working, the 2ND CALL
    }

useEffect(() => {
        if (user !== null) {
            
                //getJoinedList()
                calling()
            
        }
    }, [user])
```

But still the `getAvailableSlotList()` set hooks is not taking any effect.

Specific problem:

I noticed that, the 2nd API calling is successful, but the follow up function which I call to setting the hooks, it just not taking any effect.

Means that:
Everything in `getJoinedList()` is working just fine. But when reach to `getAvailableSlotList()`, I can get the API result from it, but the `setAvailableSlotList` and `setIsAllSlotLoading` both cant set in the value

**Question:**

1. How to call another API after 1 API call is finished?
2. How to set react hooks at the 2nd API call?

Comment: can you share the code for `getAllAvailableSlot()`?  The second attempt looks right to me. My guess is it's never reached the `.then` block.

Comment: @ClaireLin sure, wait a moment

Comment: @ClaireLin I actually using Aws amplify, so i just return a promise from the Get request. I just updated the question, pulling my hair off.. haha

Comment: The second approach you tried should be working: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bhaskara-odw6i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ClaireLin is exactly the same from what you provide. It just cant set the hooks in the `callSecond()`, I just dont know why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve promises one after another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251935/how-to-resolve-promises-one-after-another)

Comment: @ClaireLin miss ur answer helped me, it works, thank you for ur help

Comment: @ken Wrote up as a proper answer with a bit more explanation on why the first/thrid attempts didn't work. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt should work. Here is a simplified sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bhaskara-odw6i?file=/src/App.js

A bit explanation on where the first and third attempts went wrong:

The first attempt is almost there, just that you need to move `callback()` inside the `.then()` block which essentially brings you to the second attempt.

The third one you used async/await but the problem is neither `getJoinedList()` nor `getAvailableSlotList()` returns a `Promise` so both requests will be sent around the same time without one waiting on the other to resolve first.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is actually to add your entire getAllAvailableSlot() function inside the getUserJoinedSlotList() through chaining. I see you're already using that, so I don't need to explain it in depth.

```
getUserJoinedSlotList().then(res => {
    --- logic ---
    getAllAvailableSlot().then(res2 => {
       -- logic ---
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then chaining and its pairing could work here.

```
await getUserJoinedSlotList()
    .then(res => /*assign hooks data*/)
    .then(() => getAllAvailableSlot())
    .then(availableSlot => /*assign availableSlot data*/)
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```